# Updating a has_many :through association with a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to update the form for a Song model that has multiple Genres through a song_genre_relationships model. I'd prefer to update the genre id's for any given song through an array in the form field.

I suspect my controller is off, but I'm still pretty new to Rails and am unsure.

Here are my models, form and controller.

EDITED BASED ON meagar's RESPONSE BELOW.

song.rb

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :song_genre_relationships
    has_many :genres, :through => :song_genre_relationships

end
```

song_genre_relationships.rb

```
class SongGenreRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :song
    belongs_to :genre

end
```

genre.rb

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :song_genre_relationships
    has_many :songs, :through => :song_genre_relationships

end
```

song_controller.rb

```
class SongController < ApplicationController

    def update
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])

    relationships = @song.song_genre_relationships
    @genres = Genre.all
    @genres.each do |genre|
        unless relationships.detect { |g| g.genre_id == genre.id }
            relationships.build genre_id: genre.id
        end
    end

    if @song.update_attributes(song_params)

        flash[:notice] = "Song updated successfully."

        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
        render('edit')
    end
end

private
def song_params
    params.require(:song).permit(:name, :genre_ids => [])
end
```

_form.html.erb (song form)

```
<%= form_for(@song) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name, 'Title' %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :genre_ids, 'Genres' %>
    <%= f.text_area :genre_ids %>


<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
  @genres = params[:song][:genre_ids]
    Array(@genres).each do |genre|
        unless relationships.detect { |g| g.genre_id == genre.id }
            relationships.build genre_id: genre
        end
    end
```

`params[:song][:genre_ids]` is a string. It contains, in your example, `"[<whatever id's input to the form>]"`.

You're wrapping it in an array with `Array(@genres)`. Now, you have an array containing a single item, which is the string. Then you iterate over that single item, placing it into `genre` inside the loop

Then you test `g.genre_id == genre.id`. `genre` is that string, and you're invoking `.id` on it, hence your error.

It's impossible to tell what you're trying to do, but you definitely cannot invoke `.id` on a string and expect to get the ID of some database record back.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you have a recommendation for how I could input multiple genre_ids into a form field and have them each inserted as a single record into my song_genre_relationships join table? I've updated my initial controller code to where it updates individual records in the join model, but since I have @genre = Genre.all, all genres are being added to any song I'm updating through the form. Maybe if I change that line to reflect the form input, I'll be on the right track? Again, thanks so much, I'm so new at this...